The error is: passing argument 5 of 'init_node' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    char initial_req_item[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][10] = {" ", "свиня", "меч"};
    int initial_req_val[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT] = {0, 1, 1};
    int is_initial_req[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT] = {0, 1, 1};
    char initial_opt[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][100] = {"Искам броня", "Убих оная свиня дето ми заръча", "Дай да говоря с кагана"};
    TreeNode* my_root = init_node("Съмнителен индивид- Добре дошъл в нашия град. Добре дошъл в България. С какво мога да ти помогна?", initial_opt, 0, is_initial_req, initial_req_item, initial_req_val);

I get the error when passing the initial_req_item parameter, but I can't find a way to deal with it since the function expects multidimensional array of characters and I give it a 2 multidimensional array of characters
TreeNode* init_node(char NPC[500], char PLAYER[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][100], int cycle, int IS_REQ[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT], char REQ_ITEMS[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][100], char REQ_VALS[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT])


The array sizes don't match up.

It wants char REQ_ITEMS[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][100] (which decays to char (*)[100] but you're passing it char initial_req_item[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT][10] (which decays to char (*)[10]). Only the first layer of arrays decay to pointers, so the rest of the sizes have to match still. If that's too limiting for you, consider changing to a type like char ** (i.e., an array of pointers instead of an array of arrays).

If the strings aren't modified, const char *initial_req_item[MAX_ANSWER_COUNT] and const char **REQ_ITEMS would do. It would be preferable, even
